# How do I show the line number and frame in a catch exception?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write the line number and frame to a text file but I cannot get it to work.  From what I've read online the way I've written this should work but it's not actually outputting any line numbers making my debugging quite hard.  Can anyone assist in perhaps pointing out where my code could be wrong?

```
catch (Exception e)
        {                
            var st = new StackTrace(e, true);
            var frame = st.GetFrame(0);
            var line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
            var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename, true);

            sw.WriteLine(
                DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\r\n" 
                + e.Message + "\r\n" 
                + e.InnerException + "\r\n"                    
                + e.Source + "\r\n"
                + frame + "\r\n" 
                + line);
            sw.Close();

        }
```

It does output some information just not the line / frame numbers.

Here is an example of what's getting output.

```
22/08/2016 08:34:24
Input string was not in a correct format.
StringToNumber at offset 12099653 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0 0
```

Also please note the application is running in Debug not Release.

Comment: And what does it print instead? And hint: You really shouldn't put such code directly in your catch block. Instead: define some methods/interfaces to do such logging for you; and only call those methods in your catch. Or do you intend to copy this code to each and every catch block? And, finally: shouldn't you **absolutely** make sure that **no other** exception can be thrown in your catch block? The last thing you want to happen at runtime is that exceptions from your "production code" get lost ... because of follow-on exceptions trying to log stuff in your catch block?!

Comment: Can you check that the PDB file(s) for the code are loaded in memory? You can quickly check that by setting a breakpoint in the code and running the code, and if the red circle isn't fully coloured, that means the symbols (PDB file) is not loaded. Without that file loaded, the line number will always be 0.

Comment: I doubt you can get file name and line number if the exception happens in one of .Net assemblies (e.g mscorlib), unless you somehow use pdb files for these assemblies - If I'm not wrong, you can download them from Microsoft

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your application is built in DEBUG mode. If it is in Release, than some information like line numbers are not included in exception texts.

Another possible reason is that you edited Debug configuration for your project and disabled debug information (Project settings => Build => Advanced => Output debug info )

And finally you need pdb files for line numbers and they should be in same folders as your .exe / .dll. By default, they are there, until you manually remove them or copy parts of your application to another location and run there.

Comment: You can have line numbers in RELEASE builds - you just need to have the PDB.

Comment: All the above seems to be in order mate.